# How to pass more that 255 characters in parameter in vba?

Tags: vba

I have a button and I pass String as parameter. If string parameter increase more that 255 characters, it doesn't get any value. If string parameter is less than 255 characters, it is working fine.

Here is my code:

```
Dim parameterText As String
parameterText = "First Parameter Value | Third Parameter Value | Third Parameter Value"
Dim AdviceItem As CommandBarButton
Set AdviceItem = CategoryItem.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)               
With AdviceItem
    .Caption = adviceText
    .Visible = True
    .Parameter = strParameter
    .OnAction = "myFunction"
End With

Sub myFunction()
    Dim parameters() As String
    ReDim parameters(3)
    Dim parameterText As String
    parameterText = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
    'parameterText is blank if there are more than 255 characters passed from above function
    MsgBox ("parameterText" & parameterText)
    parameters() = Split(parameterText, "|")
End Sub
```

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve it?

Comment: No its not. VB string type can hold data more than 255 character.

Comment: use a string?????? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have updated my question.

Comment: probably not a string issue, more likely a limitation on commandbutton.parameter but it's not documented. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861822.aspx)  I'd try storing your parameters in an array/dictionary and using the id/key as a parameter.

Comment: @Phil Can you give me example about how to pass parameters in array/dictionary that you have tried? It will be helpful to get some idea. (there can be 100 buttons and that all initialize when Ms Word started. In short, above code is execute when Word start and button click event will fire when user click.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a limitation on the .parameter, you can bypass this by using an array to store the string you want to display.

```
 Option Explicit

    Public AllParameters(100) As String
    Public AllAdviceTexts(100) as String


    Sub defineParameters()

    AllParameters(0) = "First Parameter Value"
    AllParameters(1) = "Third Parameter Value "
    AllParameters(2) = "Third Parameter Value "
    'etc
'set advice texts here too    

    End Sub


    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim AdviceItem As CommandBarButton
    Dim i As Integer
    Call defineParameters
    For i = 0 To 100

    Set AdviceItem = CategoryItem.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
    With AdviceItem
        .Caption = AllAdviceTexts(i)
        .Visible = True
        .Parameter = i
        .OnAction = "myFunction"
    End With

    Next i

    End Sub


    Sub myFunction()
        Dim parameterText As String
        Dim index As Integer
        index = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
        parameterText = AllParameters(index)
        MsgBox ("parameterText" & parameterText)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No its not. VB string type can hold data more than 255 character.

A variable-length string can contain up to approximately 2 billion (2^31) characters

A fixed-length string can contain 1 to approximately 64K (2^16) characters.

and for SPLIT you can try like below

```
Dim LString As String
Dim LArray() As String

LString = "foobar.com"
LArray = Split(LString, ".")

MsgBox LArray(0)
MsgBox LArray(1)
```

Note: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Try to use below code if you get some idea.

```
Function Over255()

    Dim myArray(3)  As String '<<<<< not variant

    myArray(0) = String(300, "a")
    myArray(1) = String(300, "b")
    myArray(2) = String(300, "c")
    myArray(3) = String(300, "d")

    'Over255 = Application.Transpose(myArray())
    Over255 = TR(myArray)

End Function

'like Application.Transpose...
Function TR(arrIn) As String()
    Dim arrOut() As String, r As Long, ln As Long, i As Long

    ln = (UBound(arrIn) - LBound(arrIn)) + 1
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ln, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    For r = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn)
        arrOut(i, 1) = arrIn(r)
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    TR = arrOut

End Function
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please suggest me accordingly.

Comment: The maximum length of text on MsgBox is approximately 1024 characters, depending on the width of the characters used. Did you checked whether Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter line giving you any ouput. Try to get first 50 character.

Comment: I have tried 2 cases. 1- I have passed 244 character in parameter. On other side `parameterText = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter` returns all 244 character........ 2- I have passed 259 character in parameter. On other side `parameterText = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter` returns blank. I really need to manage this. Please suggest if you have any idea.